# ElementRef is causing cross site scripting attack : DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

With ElementRef able to use nativeElement and it's working fine, but throwing cross site scripting

```
 @ViewChild("file", { static: true }) file: ElementRef;
this.file.nativeElement.onchange = async function () {....}
```

I've tried using Renderer2 but not able to use nativeElement any alternate suggestions for nativeElement

```
 @ViewChild("file", { static: true }) file: Renderer2;
this.file.nativeElement.onchange = async function () {....}
```

Comment: Can you share the template, and file is component type or it is an id in the template ?

Comment: @AbelValdez it's an id in template

Comment: Can you post the template part?

Comment: check this it might help you
https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/spasecurity/angular-xss.html